# Import lPython to debug a program

Tags: python, import

Someone explain to me instead of verifying your python code program with some `print` function, it is suggested to use :

```
import lPython
lPython.embed()
```

As I don't have I lot of experience with python, could anyone be able to show me how it work with an example? And maybe how to understand each statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a typo with IPython.

Here is an example:

```
a = 1

from IPython import embed # please notice the 'I' not the 'l'
embed()

c = 2
```

What this line of code does - it stops execution of your program and runs python session which allows you to introspect values. For instance if I run this code:

```
python tmp.py
```

It will stop the execution, run python and it will show you an ipython interpepator.

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

If you type 'who' there you will list of all variables defined **before** ipython was called. See more information here: [ipythondocs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding)

## however

I would strongly recommend to get familiar with pdb or ipdb.
Check documentation here [pdbdocs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). It is much more easier and gives you an ability of actual debugging of the code as in previous solution any changes you make - will not affect execution runtime.